# Circle CI integration on Android with external module hosted on a different github repository

Tags: android, git, github, circleci

I have an Android project with my own external module hosted on a different github repository. On my `settings.gradle` I set this module as follows:

```
include ':common'
project(':common').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../android-common/common')
```

Currently, Circle doesn't build my project because it obviously doesn't know about my `android-common` folder.

Is there a way I could set this up to make my build work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually tell CircleCI to pull down that repo in `circle.yml`.

First, for the correct permissions, you'd need to setup a '[User Key](https://circleci.com/docs/github-security-ssh-keys/#security)'. This gives CircleCI access to that external module.

Then, you can run a `git clone` in `circle.yml` in whatever phase makes sense for you. Sounds like

```
dependencies:
  pre:
```

might be a good section. Depending on your needs, having the module as a Git Submodule is [supported as well](https://circleci.com/docs/external-resources/).

-Ricardo
CircleCI Developer Evangelist

Comment: Thanks! Will it clone on a sibling folder so that `../android-common/common` works?

Comment: PS: If you upvote my question, I will have enough reputation to upvote your answer. I would like to do that. ;)

Comment: You can run any Bash commands you want in `circle.yml` so you can clone to that directory if you would like.

Comment: @FelicianoTech The links you have added are broken, can you rectify those?